# How to give a bonus to an answer that was not accepted after the question was closed

Tags: discussion, support

I recently asked a question
[about (not) reading Shakespeare in class](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/257088/a-short-story-about-not-reading-shakespeare-in-class).
Two correct answers arrived within a few seconds of each other.

It also rapidly appeared that the question was a dupe.

I wanted to follow user14111's advice to "green check" one answer and give a bonus to the other one. But it seems the only way is to start a bounty. Which needs 48 hours delay. So I **carefully did not** accept either answer, to wait till I could start the bounty. I wanted to start it, wait for another 24 hours to grant it to one answer and finally "green check" the other one. At which point the question would be closed a dupe.

But since I made clear in my comments that the answers were correct, my question was closed before I could create the bounty. Even though I had **not** "green check" either answer.  Curiously, I was still able to "green check" one answer after the question was closed.

How can I give the bonus to the other one ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can accept answers after a question is closed - acceptance and closure are independent.

But **you can't start bounties on a closed question**. In fact, it goes the other way too: you can't vote to close a question that has an open bounty on it. Bounties and closure block each other. Probably this is because most bounty reasons are to *attract* new answers rather than reward existing ones, and closure blocks new answers.

In this case, if your goal is simply to give some extra reputation award to the person whose answer you didn't accept, you could find another worthy answer from that user and set a bounty there instead. (Bounties can be set on any open question, not only your own. There's even a badge for bountying someone else's question.)

Comment: I did realise by myself I **could** do that. But I thought a bit "unethical" to pick up a different answer, totally unrelated. But if **you** suggest it, then I'll do it.

Comment: @Alfred It's been done before on this site, people awarding bounties e.g. for favours in chat. Not technically a proper use of bounties, but OK if it's not overdone. Just choose a *good* answer to bounty, please :-)

Comment: OK, I just started a bounty on an excellent answer by DavidW (his best one, as a matter of fact) which, in addition, had never been formally accepted. For the record, I want to mention that the bounty I started a few hours ago on a question of a different OP to give a bonus to user14111 is  because I think unfair that the OP **never accepted** it, not to thank him for advice in  comments, even though he did give me good advices.

Comment: @Alfred It is a shame when OPs don't accept correct answers, but if you give bounties to all those answers, you'll run out of rep very soon :-)

Comment: Well, for DavidW it is because I could not accept both answers to **my** question. And for user14111, I felt concerned about that particular story. His answer contained all the references I was looking for, in a question that was a dupe of one of mine that was answered by a third party. I don't plan to make that a general practice.